# Remove border/margin around ::after css pseudo element

Tags: html, css

How can i remove the organge border arround the ::after css pseude element just like i postet in my fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/53ekh8ps/

```
#login_table tr:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+4) td:first-child, #login_table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
    background:orange;
}

#login_table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)::after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    background:black;
    width:100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add `padding: 0` to `#login_table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)`:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

#login_table {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 50%;
}

#login_table tr:first-child td,
#login_table tr:last-child td {
  height: 10%;
  background: red;
}

#login_table tr:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+4) td:first-child,
#login_table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
  background: orange;
}

#login_table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}

#login_table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="login_table">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This can also be seen **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/nm8vjgrd/)**.

Comment: thx for your help, but in Microsoft EDGE this does'nt proper work, is their any workarround?